# How to change a UIButton size and position through code not storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, size, uistoryboard

Ive been messing around trying to change the size of a button in my storyboard scene through code, but every time I load the scene the button size is unchanged. I've tried changing the frame size of the button when the view loads, and I've also tried changing the frame through CGRect, and none of them seem to work. for example:

```
clickerbutton.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 1000, height: 1000)
```

or

```
 clickerbutton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
```

Comment: where you put this code? please describe it in detail.

Comment: I've tried this in the view did load section of the game view controller that manages the scene, and it does nothing, however when i try implementing it in the view did load portion of my actual game scene, the app crashes and gives me an error before even loading

Comment: crashes before loading may result from the storyboard. is there a constraint on your clickerbutton?

Comment: Are you setting constraints for the button in story board?

Comment: There arent any constraints in my storyboard since i am trying to set everything through code and make size and position relative to scene scize

Comment: @Chris Hutchison please check my answer and reply..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are not using **AutoLayout**, as using autoLayout will not allow you to modify button size

Try using :-

```
 let dummyBtn : UIButton = UIButton() 

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    dummyBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 150)
    dummyBtn.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    self.view.addSubview(dummyBtn)
    print(dummyBtn.frame)

}

func someFunction(){
  dummyBtn.frame = CGRectMake(x: 10, y: 10, width: 1000, height: 1000)
     }
```

Comment: The problem was auto layout and size classes, sorry took a while to get back to you

Answer (score 0):

To programatically layout button:

Add IBOutlets for each constraints of your button and change them in code.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myButtonTopSpaceConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myButtonLeadingSpaceConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myButtonWidthConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myButtonHeightConstraint;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.myButtonLeadingSpaceConstraint.constant = 10;
    self.myButtonTopSpaceConstraint.constant =  20;
    self.myButtonWidthConstraint.constant = 200;
    self.myButtonHeightConstraint.constant = 70;

}
```

Use the following GitHub link to download sample project:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/ButtonCustomLayout

If you want without constraints:

Create the button programmatically and then change frame as you want.